# Tips for reducing battery drain for android services?

Tags: android, android-service

I wrote an app recently and, well I'm quite disappointed about how much battery the service consumes. I go to make a call yesterday to find my battery is at 9%; I check the android system statics for the battery and find that my app is responsible for 60% of the battery drainage

My question is, what can one do to reduce the battery usage on an app that runs and then `sleep`s for 60 seconds? The service is reading from a SQLite database; I could cache the data, but would that really account for that much battery usage? What are some standard ways to reduce battery drainage in a service?

Comment: Are you specifically keeping the phone alive so your service continues running? Typically you'd want to use a [repeating Alarm](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) to wake the phone up to do something every so often, and let it *really* sleep rather than `sleep()`. Also, do you really need to read from a SQLite database every minute? What's writing to the database that you need to check? Or are you checking for something in the database to be due that you could maybe instead schedule an Alarm for instead?

Comment: Well, there's a start: why keep a partial wake lock? An alarm will wake the phone even from sleep (i.e. even if the CPU is *not* running). I think we could use some more detail on why you need to do something once a minute—the more information we have as to your fundamental requirements, the more sensible the suggestions we can make... But getting rid of that wake lock that's keeping your phone's CPU running all day will be a good start, I'm sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into using [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to schedule your app or service to be called when necessary. This has a big advantage over your current wake lock method, because even a partial wake lock will keep the CPU running. An AlarmManager alarm can wake the phone even from CPU sleep.

Basically, get rid of your existing wake lock and schedule an AlarmManager alarm—which can repeat once a minute, if that's what you need—to wake up the device, if necessary, and send you a message.

The AlarmManager itself will take out a wake lock while calling an onReceive() method to notify you of the alarm, and relinquish it when onReceive() finishes, letting the phone go back into deep sleep if it wants to.

Note that this means that if you want to do extended work—e.g. firing something off on a background thread—you'll probably want to take your own wake lock out in onReceive() and relinquish it when your work is done, otherwise the phone may go to sleep while you're in the middle of the work.

This is all pretty well-explained in [the AlarmManager docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html), but the best explanation I've seen is in Mark Murphy's [The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development](http://commonsware.com); he also provides [a library for exactly this pattern on Github](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful). Definitely worth a look.